# Сложная группировка по Value в Dictionary (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Имеется класс:

```cs
public class ExportData {

    public Dictionary<string, object> DataHolder { get; set; }

    public ExportData() {
        DataHolder = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

Далее создаётся `List` подобных объектов, каждый из которых содержит ключ - название свойства (для всех объектов набор ключей одинаков) и значение - значение данного свойства для данного объекта.

Задача проста - сгруппировать всё это по нескольким полям.

Например, группировка по одному полю проходит спокойно:

```cs
var result = exportData.GroupBy(c => c.DataHolder["Field name 1"]).ToList();
```

Нужно что-то вроде подобного:

```cs
var groups = people.GroupBy(c => new {
    c.Country,
    c.Gender
});
```

Для класса со стандартными свойствами всё хорошо. Но для моего случая так не работает:

```cs
var result = exportData.GroupBy(c => new {
    c.DataHolder["Field 1"],
    c.DataHolder["Field 2"]
});
```

> Ошибка: "Неверное определение члена анонимного типа. Члены анонимного типа должны быть объявлены присваиванием члена, простым именем или доступом к члену."

Как сделать эту группировку? Поля будут подбираться каждый раз новые, то есть вместо "Field 1" будет переменная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = exportData.GroupBy(c => new
{
    Field1 = c.DataHolder["Field 1"],
    Field2 = c.DataHolder["Field 2"]
});
```

Comment: Всё. Пошёл я спать. Мне компилятор уже в упор говорит что сделать, а я не понимаю))

Comment: @AleksKeller бывает :)